# Cant change Target Framework (Could not resolve mscorlib)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-5, .net-4.7.2

I opened a new project, I noticed that Target Framework is net 5. I used to work on 4.7.2 so I searched for it and did not find it. Knowing that I have two projects in which I use 4.7.2 and they work well, I tried to modify the .vbproj file and make it like this

```
<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
```

All versions of .net have appeared after I restarted the project, but an error message appears when I am modifying the form design

```
Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'.  This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted.
```

or

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse..ctor(IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution projectAssemblyResolution, IVsSmartOpenScope dispenser)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse.GetUniverse(IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution projectAssemblyResolution, IVsSmartOpenScope dispenser)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkProvider..ctor(IVsDesignTimeAssemblyResolution assemblyResolution, IDesignTimeAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, TypeDescriptionProvider parentProvider, IVsSmartOpenScope openScope)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VsTargetFrameworkProviderService.get_TargetFrameworkProvider()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VsTargetFrameworkProviderService.GetProvider(Type type)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

i deleted the form and created a new form in the hope that it would work, but the problem was not solved,
What is the cause of the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot (easily) change a project from .NET 5.0 to .NET Framework 4.8 or earlier. That's because .NET 5.0 is .NET Core, not .NET Framework. If you want to target .NET Framework then you have to create a project that targets .NET Framework in the first place. Pay attention to the project template you use when you create a new project. If the name includes "(.NET)" then that is .NET Core and will generally default to .NET 5.0 but can be changed to .NET Core 3.1 or earlier. If you want to target .NET Framework then select a project template with "(.NET Framework)" in the name.

Comment: lol yup i dont see this difference xD thx man